# I want to create this environment variable for everyone, but it does not load during startup? (linux)

Tags: python, linux, unix, environment-variables

I put this at the top, using "sudo vi /etc/profile":

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/myuser:/home/myotheruser
```

When I use putty and log in under my username, the python path does not work!
I type "set", and it is there. But, importing things from that directory still does not work.

When I manually do this, then it will work.

```
EXPORT PYTHONPATH=/home/myuser:/home/myotheruser
```

However, I don't want to do that everytime. I simply want this path to be appended to everyone, at startup.

Comment: Just a note: It's not a good idea to have user's configuration rely on other user's home files.  Unless "myotheruser" needs to be able to modify those files regularly, you should install them under /usr/local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *export* the PYTHONPATH even in /etc/profile.

Make sure you have these lines both in /etc/profile.

```
PYTHONPATH=...
export PYTHONPATH
```

After that login again.